# Google Maps API Embed - Allow scrolling without holding down ctrl key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Embed API, with `iframe`.

Sample code:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

By default, when you are scrolling on the `iframe`, you get [a message telling you to hold down ctrl key](https://i.gyazo.com/0b7a11f63a27df297a556d9d57146a09.jpg) to keep scrolling, while the rest of the page keeps scrolling

I want it so that when you do not need to hold down `ctrl` key to scroll on the Embed map.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Embed API doesn't support that kind of feature. I would suggest to file for a Feature Request in our **[Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)**.

**[Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)** is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

On the other hand, you can disable it using **[Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#MapOptions.gestureHandling)**. Set ***gestureHandling*** to greedy if you prefer the map to soak up the scroll rather than the page.